# Unable to run helium with sublime text

Tags: ipython, sublimetext3, helium

I'm using sublime text 3 and I want to run ipynb files. I have installed helium. In the document, it says to execute a block I should execute `Helium: Execute Block` in the command palette. But can't seem to find that command.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1.) run %connect_info in a localhosted jupyter notebook and copy the json output

Step 2.) In sublime text editor, press "Ctrl+shift+P" and type hermes: start kernel and copy paste this json you copied from step 1.
You should see a blank page popout.

Step 3.) Open your py file you want to execute, and select the lines you want to execute using mouse and again press "Ctrl+shift+P" and type hermes: execute cell (you will see an option now), click on that and your output should run on the black page which popped out in step 2.

Note : If your localhost jupyter notebook is running in a specific folder, make sure that the py file you want to run using helium/hermes is under that jupyter notebook access, basically the py file has to be under the same folder you ran jupyter from.

Comment: Just so I understand: I can't open an existing ipynb with Hermes?

Comment: Yes, to quote its developer from Github, "If 'to edit the code from the jupyter notebook' means to edit .ipynb file directly, the answer is simply no, and it's out of the current scope of this project."